# clientlogin to wikidata through API gives ambigous error messages

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

I want to login to Wikidata using their API: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php

I had prepared a few requests and tried them against the test instance of Wikidata: https://test.wikidata.org/w/api.php. Everything worked fine and I changed the call to target the real Wikidata instead. But now the action `clientlogin` won't work, even though the settings are exactly the same as for the test instance. I have looked for documentation, but none seem to describe any differences between the test and the real instance.

I'm using Postman for making the POST requests. I have the parameters:

```
action:clientlogin
format:json
loginreturnurl:http://example.com
username:myUsername
```

and the body has format form-data with values:

```
logintoken:8227d28de0a94affe9779db047c40df8609542dc+\
password:myPassword
```

This works fine for test, but when I call the real Wikidata, I get the following error:

```
Call: https://wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=clientlogin&format=json&loginreturnurl=http://example.com&username=myUsername
{
    "error": {
        "code": "missingparam",
        "info": "The \"logintoken\" parameter must be set.",
        "*": "See https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    },
    "servedby": "mw1315"
}
```

If I put the logintoken as a parameter, I get this error:

```
Call: https://wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=clientlogin&format=json&loginreturnurl=http://example.com&logintoken=8227d28de0a94affe9779db047c40df8609542dc+\&username=myUsername
{
    "error": {
        "code": "mustpostparams",
        "info": "The following parameter was found in the query string, but must be in the POST body: logintoken.",
        "*": "See https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    },
    "servedby": "mw1289"
}
```

I have made the appropriate calls for logintokens, but I have excluded that in those calls, since I not that if it works, it will give the error of invalid token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question, I realized that the error was that when removing the subdomain test from the URL, I was supposed to replace it with www for the real Wikidata... ‍♀️ But now it works and hopefully, someone else can make use of this answer.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. I'm facing these errors still on my own wikimedia-installation. One effort led me further: the 'Content-Type'-Header in the request. make it 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and encode the content. Now I'm facing the next problem: invalid token (instead of missing token). omg... this API really sucks... And it does not really work as documented.